# add two list index wise

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I run this code I'm getting some error that I don't know how to change

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = input("enter the list 1:")
list1 = list(a.split(","))
b = input("enter the list 2:")
list2 = list(b.split(","))
if not list2:
    print(list1)
else:
    res = [i+j for i,j in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=0)]
    print("Ans: ",res)
```

it shows error:

```
res = [i+j for i,j in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=0)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Expected output:

```
enter the list 1:1,2,3
enter the list 2:1,2,3,4,5
Ans : 2,4,6,4,5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
out = [i+j for i,j in zip_longest(test_list1, test_list2, fillvalue=0)]
```

Output:

```
[5, 8, 10, 2, 10]
```

Comment: bro it shows some error above changed code can you explain it

Comment: @AbilashK.G input is type string, so you need to cinvert to type int; try with `out = [int(i)+int(j) for i,j in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=0)]`

Comment: bro it worked perfect can you explain how it processed on that line

Comment: @AbilashK.G Python `input` function converts the user input into a string (that’s why you were able to use `str.split`) and because you want to add integers, you need to cast each number to an int. As for `zip_longest`, it creates an iterator that makes tuples out of the passed lists (in this case, `list1` and `list2`) much like `zip` function. The only difference is that `zip_longest`‘s created iterator is as long as the longest of the lists (`zip` is as long as the shortest of the lists).